# Spotfire Data Table - Limit data-on-demand by expression when [Column] != "Value"

Tags: spotfire

I have what should be a simple one.  I've added a Data Table to a TIBCO Spotfire Anaylyst 7.14.0.42 report.

> +-------------+-------+------------+
>  | DEPARTMENT  | GROUP | TECHNOLOGY |
>   +-------------+-------+------------+
>  | Quality1     | TeamA | TEST       |
>  | Quality1     | TeamB | OldGen     |
>  | Quality2 | TeamA |
>   NextGen    |
>  | Quality2 | TeamB | TEST       |
>   +-------------+-------+------------+

I've marked the On-Demand settings to "Data on demand", selected the [Define Input...] button for the {Technology} column, chose "Values (fixed/properties/expression)", and for the Expression, I've tried the following:

```
If([TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY]!="TEST",[TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY],NULL)

If([TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY]="TEST",[TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY],NULL)

If([TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY]!="TEST",true,false)

If([TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY]="TEST",true,false)

true

false

[TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY]

[TECHNOLOGY]

[TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY]!="TEST"

[TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY]="TEST"
```

Each and every attempt returns a table with no rows.  What I would like to see is the following:

> +-------------+-------+------------+
>  | DEPARTMENT  | GROUP | TECHNOLOGY |
>   +-------------+-------+------------+
>  | Quality1     | TeamB | OldGen     |
>  | Quality2 | TeamA | NextGen |
>   +-------------+-------+------------+

Any clues ?

Answer (score 1):

So if I get it right, you want to display all the rows where [TECHNOLOGY] IS NOT TEST ?

Do you want this information in the data table as well? Otherwise, you can limit the data in data table. Once not in data table, the TEST related rows will never appear in Data On Demand tab.

You can achieve this easily with the following steps:

1. Right click on data table, go to properties,
2. In Data tab, slow to 'Limit data using expression',
3. Enter the following expression: `[TABLE].[TECHNOLOGY]!="TEST"`,
4. Save and close.

In this case, your data will not be visible in the data table and hence will never show up in data on demand.
More information in Spotfire documentation [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_details_on_limit_data_using_expression.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My source for the data has about 98% of rows where [TECHNOLOGY]="TEST"; the issue is that I do not want to load that data then filter it out.  In other words, I do want to not load it in the first place.  I'll have a join on this table downstream, but for now what I've done is to use a data function to output the table rows where [TECHNOLOGY]!="TEST" back into the same data table [TABLE].  It's a workaround, but it would be nice to have a more appropriate solution.  Meanwhile, I don't have access to create/edit information links either.

Comment: ohh.. I dont think there is any other solution apart from changing the information link. If you do anything else, the data will always be loaded first and then filtered. If you do come across any other workaround, please update in the comment.